# Style list item onMouseOver - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started with React and I am currently building a Tic Tac Toe game for learning purposes. When the user hovers over a square which is a list item, I want that square to have a background image. So far I am able to do it only if I manipulate the DOM directly like this:

```
event.target.style = <bacgroundImageUrl>
```

which of course is an anti-pattern in React

Here is what my state looks like:

```
state = {
 gameInProgress: true,
 player1Active: false,
 player2Active: false,
 board: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 squareHovered: false,
 player1Winner: false,
 player2Winner: false,
 player1BgImg: null,
 player2BgImg: null,
 tie: false,
 winner: false
}
```

This is what's inside my render function:

```
<Board>
<Squares
   bg={
       this.state.player1Active
           ? this.state.player1BgImg
       :this.state.player2Active
           ? this.state.player2BgImg
       : null}
   hovered={(event) => this.hoverOverSquare(event)}
   notHovered={(event) => this.notHoverOverSquare(event)}
   clicked={(event) => this.fillSquare(event,
       this.state.player1Active
           ? this.playersData.player1Sign
       : this.state.player2Active
           ? this.playersData.player2Sign
       : null
    )}/>
</Board>
```

And also the  component:

```
const Squares = (props) => {
let squares = [];

for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    squares.push(
        <li
            id={i}
            key={i}
            style={props.bg}
            onClick={props.clicked}
            onMouseLeave={props.notHovered}
            onMouseOver={props.hovered}
            className="box">
        </li>
    )
}

 return squares;
}
```

As you may already know this applies background image to all list items(squares). So, I am just not able to find a way of solving this. Any help and criticism will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done entirely by CSS switching class on property className of your cell.
Note also style need a object to be fed. Also property name that contain a dash (IE: background-image) need to be converted in camelcase (IE: backgroundImage)

```js
<MyComponent style={{ backgroundImage: 'url: http://myurl.jpg' }} />
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't a classes switch like this also be considered as a direct DOM manipulation?

Comment: I just saw your code snippet. Isn't this ternary check that I do in the "bg" on the <Squares> component doing exactly the same? It feds the style property an image based on which player is active now.

Comment: The problem is the value of the props not wrapped in a object with correct camelled cases

Comment: Maybe I did not explain well. The problem actually is that every list item gets the background image when a single list item is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

As you have just begun with react, I will just tell you what to do, so that you could actually implement it and learn some.

1. Create css class which has a background image set wrt the dimensions similar to that of a square. On hovering a square just pass the class to the `style` e.g.. `style={someClass}`.

> This is simple and but will have same background image displayed for
>   all squares, individually.

---

2. Create a class like above except, don't mention the background image. You can setup background image in state and pass it to the `<li>` through style with the created class. e.g.. `<li style={{backgroundImage: 'some/loc/file.format'}} className={holderClass}>`

> With this, you can actually send custom image to each square (stored
>   and retrieved from react `state`)